# How to use JQuery to identify CSS 'text-decoration'

Tags: jquery, css

A rather obvious-sounding answer, as you'd think the answer was along the lines of:

```
$(theelement).css('text-decoration');
```

where 'theelement' is the actual one concerned (using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp)).

My problem is whenever I try this it always returns something in the format of

```
none solid rgb(0, 0, 0)
```

which looks very much like a border CSS, rather than a text-decoration CSS.

I've put it into a Fiddle to demonstrate this in a simple way: [click for this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevepitman/p4HJV/)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `text-decoration` !== `text-direction`

Comment: do you mean `text-direction` or `text-decoration` ? because there is no `text-direction` ,only `direction` in css

Comment: `text-direction` doesn't exist. there is only a `direction` property in css . refer http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/direction

Comment: @Lix He is saying about `text-direction` and NOT `text-decoration`

Comment: Changed 'direction' (my typo in the description, not the JSFiddle code) to 'decoration'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration):

> **Note**: CSS Text Decoration Level 3 transformed this property as a shorthand for the three new `text-decoration-color`, `text-decoration-line`, and `text-decoration-style` CSS properties.

So when you read the property, you get all three component properties. If you don't want all three properties, specify the one(s) you want, e.g.

```
$(theelement).css('text-decoration-line')
```

will return `none`.

Comment: Thanks Bamar - looks like I was (wrongly) taking guidance from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp where it suggests there's only ONE property for 'text-decoration' (i.e. the type of line effect) rather than the THREE you suggest.

Comment: @Steve don't use [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: Barmar solution did not give answer of question because text-decoration-color, text-decoration-line, and text-decoration-style gives only inherit and initial value and did not gives the underline,line-through etc...So use                               var str = $.trim(test).split(" ");
 test= (str[0]);

Comment: @Gautam Better would be to specify the particular properties you want explicitly. I've updated the answer to show an example.

Comment: Barmar sorry for that because i test it at chrome browser which returns undefined but at firefox it returns fine.                
http://jsfiddle.net/p4HJV/2/